# asp.net mvc c# random generating same number

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how can i generate different number,it is generating the same number

```
Random rand = new Random(100000);
rand.Next();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just remove the seed number in the constructor. This seed is essentially a number from which the random number list is generated. If you specify a constant number, your random number list will always be the same.

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.Next();
```

Comment: will it restrict the number of characters generated or it can generate 10000 or 1000000000

Comment: I don't think that there is a limit to the amount of number generated. It is also unrelated to a numbers of character since the `.Next()` method returns a 32-bit signed integer greater than or equal to zero and less than MaxValue.

Answer (score 8):

Your specifying the same seed try this.

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.Next();
```

This will use the default seed which is the time.

"Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent default seed value."

As per MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Re your comment above, how to generate a "random" number in a set range.

```
// Generate and display 5 random integers from 50 to 100.
Console.WriteLine("Five random integers between 50 and 100:");
Console.Write("{0,8:N0}", rand.Next(50, 101));
```

(Taken from MSDN link above) You can now generate whatever range you want.

Comment: There's a potential problem with using the default time-based seed. For a multi-threaded app running on a multi-core processor, it becomes relatively likely for two different threads to generate the exact same random value (since it becomes possible for them to grab the exact same system time and thus produce the same value). I'd use a hash of a Guid.NewGuid() as the seed instead.

Comment: If you were devolping such an application then correct, however the use of the Random() class shouldnt be used for anything other than making things appear random.

Comment: The question is tagged with "asp.net" which is exactly the kind of multi-threaded environment that can produce these kinds of issues. Two users hitting the same code at the same time might see the same "random" values.

Comment: +1 for mentioning rand.Next(Min, max);. Was going to put an answer that added that. Emphasize the 101 to generate 50 to 100.

Comment: @LukeH - I dont agree disagree. Its just not what he asked :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure exactly what you are after!

```
Random rand = new Random(Environment.TickCount);
rand.Next();
```

Comment: +1 while the tickcount isn't a great seed it's atleast dynamic and for general purposes probably *good enough*.

Comment: In the future, it might be better not to attempt to answer a question when, as you say, you are not sure exactly what they are after.

Comment: ok thanks, looks like I assumed the same as everyone else anyway :)

Comment: The default `Random` constructor uses `Environment.TickCount` anyway. There's no need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: @LukeH - thanks, Just thought it was a fair way to specify a seed, didnt know it actually used it!

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.Next(0,1000); // minimum = 0, maximum = 999
```

Comment: Worth saying that the minimum is inclusive, the maximum is exclusive. The above will generate a number in the (inclusive) range 0-999.

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rand=new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
rand.Next();
```

This always works for me.

Comment: Why not just `new Random()`, since it uses `Environment.TickCount` as the default seed?

Comment: @LukeH: do you have any documentation on that? All I've ever seen documented is that it's seeded with a time-based value, which doesn't necessarily mean it's using `Environment.TickCount`.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: I think it's an implementation detail rather than a specified guarantee, but it's easy enough to confirm for yourself using ILDASM or Reflector. Or doing something like `var r1 = new Random(); var r2 = new Random(Environment.TickCount); while (true) Console.WriteLine(r1.Next() == r2.Next());` should display "true" continuously unless you're *really* unlucky and the two constructors run on either side of a tick.